# Sencha Touch selectfield cannot display value from datastore

Tags: sencha-touch, store

I'm trying to load a store into a Select field in sencha touch 2.0 but got a strange proble:
For following code:

```
        {
            xtype : 'list',
            store : 'Docbases',
            itemTpl : 'Hello {docbase}!'
        }, {
            xtype : 'selectfield',
            label : 'Docbase',
            id : 'docbase',
            store : 'Docbases',
            displayField : 'docbase',
            valueField : 'docbase',
            placeHolder : 'Select a Value'

        }
```

The list component can display well, while selectfield cannot display the value. When click on that selectfield, I got a console error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'get' of null
```

My Store is declared as:

```
Ext.define('FDMobileClient.store.Docbases', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.Store',
    requires : ['FDMobileClient.model.Docbase'],
    model : 'FDMobileClient.model.Docbase',
    autoLoad : true,
    proxy : {
        type : 'ajax',
        url : '/MobileInternalProject/mobile/getDocbaseList.action',
        reader : {
            type : 'json',
            root : 'docbases'
        }
    },

});
```

Does anyone have any ideas what I'm doing wrong :(

I'm appreciated all of your help. Thanks

Long

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your store seems fine to me. That's what I did to get is sorted:

- in your view config:

  ```
  config: {
     ...
     docStore : null
     ...
  },
  ```
- in your view init:

  ```
  initialize: function() {
     ...
     docStore = Ext.create('FDMobileClient.store.Docbases');
     ...
  },
  ```
- finally the code for your selectfield

  ```
  {
      xtype : 'list',
      store : 'Docbases',
      itemTpl : 'Hello {docbase}!'
  }, {
      xtype : 'selectfield',
      label : 'Docbase',
      id : 'docbase',
      store : docStore, //NOTE: no quotes!
      displayField : 'docbase',
      valueField : 'docbase',
      placeHolder : 'Select a Value'

  }
  ```

It worked for me, it should be OK for you too. Good luck, Alex

Answer (score 1):

You should give your store an ID and use this identifier when referring to the store:

```
Ext.define('FDMobileClient.store.Docbases', {
extend : 'Ext.data.Store',
requires : ['FDMobileClient.model.Docbase'],
model : 'FDMobileClient.model.Docbase',
id : 'DocbaseStore'
...
}
{
...
store : 'DocbaseStore',
displayField : 'docbase',
...
}
```